# css animating pseudo elements affecting divs

Tags: html, css, animation

So I'm trying to make an image slider and it's all working except I'm using the :before as an animating progress bar and the :after as a play/pause icon. The whole thing is meant to pause on :hover but the problem is that the .slider :before and "after don't make the .image-container pause on :hover so it all gets out of sync. Can someone help me please

p.s. I tried making the before and after children of the .image-container but then they are moved out of frame with the animation

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.slider{
    padding:0;
    width:1280px;
    height:720px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
}
.image-container{
    width:500%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: slide 20s ease-out 0 infinite normal;
    animation: slide 20s ease-out 0 infinite mormal;
}
div.image-container img{ 
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:auto;
}
div.slider:after{
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:-688px;
    left:32px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top:24px solid transparent;
    border-left:48px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border-bottom:24px solid transparent;
    transition:all .3s;
}
div.slider:before{
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    top:700px;
    border-top:20px double rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    -webkit-animation: progress 5s ease-out -2s infinite;
    animation: progress 5s ease-out -2s infinite;
}
div.slider:hover:before{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
div.slider:hover:after{
    width:16px;
    height:48px;
    border-left:48px double rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border-top:0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom:0 solid transparent;
}
div.image-container:hover{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    0%   {right:0%;}
    10%   {right:0%;}
    15%   {right:100%;}
    35%   {right:100%;}
    40%   {right:200%;}
    60%   {right:200%;}
    65%   {right:300%;}
    85%   {right:300%;}
    90%   {right:400%;}
    100%  {right:400%;}
}
@keyframes slide{
    0%   {right:0%;}
    10%   {right:0%;}
    15%   {right:100%;}
    35%   {right:100%;}
    40%   {right:200%;}
    60%   {right:200%;}
    65%   {right:300%;}
    85%   {right:300%;}
    90%   {right:400%;}
    100%  {right:400%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes progress{
    0%   {width:0px;}
    80%  {width:1280px;}
    100%  {width:0px;}
}
@keyframes progress{
    0%   {width:0px;}
    80%  {width:1280px;}
    100%  {width:0px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="1.jpg">
        <img src="2.jpg">
        <img src="3.jpg">
        <img src="4.jpg">       
        <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe with something like this?

```
div.slider:before:hover .image-container{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
```

Comment: `div.slider:hover:before` using two pseudo elements at once will create a mess. So, please decide what to use while hovering, then code your CSS.

Comment: so I would'nt be able to do something like this?
div.slider:before:hover .image-container{
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

Comment: oh okay now I see what you mean, I fixed it with this - div.slider:hover div.image-container{
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

Comment: Did your fixed code work?

Comment: Yeah, turns out there was no need to use the :before, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS:

```css
div.slider:hover:before
```

**This is wrong way of using pseudo elements.** You have used two pseudo elements at once. This will create a mess.

So, please decide which pseudo element to use while, then you can style your page with desired CSS stylings.